# It is correctly solves this query: Draw in OpenGL/Glut circle tangent to a section carried AB passing through B and C.

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, math-software, geometric-construction

Welcome.

To do that i only have got:

- point `A(Ax,Ax)`
- point `B(Bx,By)` - start
- point `C(Bx,By)` - end

**Let's compute:**

And it's good way? If no, why?

So to draw a cricle we need radius and center and angle. To get that im doing:

Let `I((B.x + C.x) / 2, (B.y + C.y) / 2)` be the middle point of [BC] and `I'(I.x + I.y - C.y, I.y + C.x - I.x)` (90° rotation of C around I).

Then the perpendicular to `(BC)` going through `I is I + tII'` (for any real number t).

Likewise with`B' be the 90° rotation of A around B,` the perpendicular to (AB) going through `B is B + uBB'` (for any real number u).

So i have `center` and `radius`. One think is left i need start angle and end angle.

```
startAngle = atan2(B.y - centerArc.y, B.x - centerArc.x);
endAngle = atan2(C.y - centerArc.y, C.x - centerArc.x);
```

- Actualy atan2 making significant confusion - is there any other way
  to calculate the start and eng angle?

And now im actualy stuck becouse I have problems with appropriate term direction to draw a circle.

This gif show how it should be: [link to gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFBNy.gif)
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Circles tangent to a given line ($AB$) at a given point ($B$) are all related by a similarity transformation centered at the point.

To make one of those circles go through a second point ($C$ in this question), draw any tangent circle at $B$ and its intersection $X$ with line $BC$, then rescale that circle by a factor of $CB/XB$ to make it reach $C$.

From this construction it follows that no square roots are necessary in the formula for the circle when using Cartesian coordinates.  For example, if the line were $y=0$ and $B=(0,0)$ then the family of circles is $x^2 + (y-a)^2 = a^2$ or $x^2 + y^2 - 2ay = 0$, and to make this pass through $(p,q)$, set $x=p, y=q$ in the equation to determine $a$.

Comment: i dont get "draw **any tangent circle** at B and its intersection X with line BC and its **intersection X with line  BC**" could u please explain me this?

Comment: Let "line PQ" mean the straight line through (distinct) points P and Q. There are many circles tangent to line AB at the point B.  Draw one of them, it does not matter what radius it has.  Call this circle "K".  Define point X as the intersection of K with line BC.

Comment: could you made graphics idea? What is `intersection of K` ?

Comment: The circle K intersects the line BC at two points, B (by definition) and X.  Line/circle intersection usually requires a square root, but not if you have the coordinates of a point known to be on the circle (B, in this case).

Comment: could you show me where that cricle should be to made circle tangent to line AB at the point B? Actualy i dont get your idea. Im trying to resolve this idea using this tool: https://www.geogebra.org/graphing, could you use this too to show me how it should be looking? Please.