# How to rescale the circle by a factor of CB/XB to make it reach C

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, soft-question, algorithms

Circles tangent to a given line `(AB)` at a given point `(B)` are all related by a similarity transformation centered at the point.

Point is given like on [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQRyr.png).

**The problem is... How to reach this idea:**

To make one of those circles go through a second point `(C in this question)`, draw any tangent circle at `B` and its intersection `X` with line `BC`, then rescale that circle by a factor of `CB/XB` to make it reach `C`.

My question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1920576/364639).

Comment: Are you asking for how to draw a circle that goes through any given point C (not on AB) and is tangent to AB at B?

Comment: @Mick i eddited my question.

Comment: Let $PB \bot AB$. The perpendicular bisector of BC will cut PB at K. The required circle is centered at K and radius = KB.

Comment: Could you present your thesis in a geometrically? For example using this: https://www.geogebra.org/graphing

Answer (score 1):

Let PB⊥AB. The perpendicular bisector of BC will cut PB at K. The required circle is centered at K and radius = KB.

[image]

If this is what you are asking for, then the scale factor trick becomes not necessary.